# How do I securely type a password on somebody else's Windows/Linux computer that I am controlling via TeamViewer/Skype

Tags: security, passwords, skype, teamviewer, screen-sharing

I need to type a password on somebody else's computer as I control that computer via Skype / TeamViewer. The computer can be Windows, Mac or LInux.

The password will be in stars (***) as I type, so it is not visible.

However, the owner of the computer may install keystroke tracking software, so I cannot type it.

If I copy paste it directly through TeamViewer, the owner may access his clipboard later. Is it possible for me to delete his clipboard history after he typed it, but not revealing the clipboard content while doing this?

How do I input this password and ensure that the owner of the computer cannot know it?

Comment: You don't. If the machine you're typing on is compromised there isn't anything you can do. Depending on what that password is for you might be able to generate a password for that specific user in which case a "leak" shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Maybe someone can help on the cryptography section on stack exchange.

Comment: This is the sort of situation where 2FA OTP comes in very handy. It doesn't matter if the OTP code is compromised, it'll invalidate within seconds

Answer (score 4):

As you already have understand it it easy to steal a password on the remote computer you are connected with via TeamViewer.

Form a technical point of view there is absolutely nothing you can do to prevent this password theft.

Therefore I only see a possibility to minimize the risk:

Before entering the password in the TeamViewer session **change the password of the service you want to enter to a randomly generated password**. If the password is leaked the attacker only gets the randomly generated password.

After you are finished doing what you want to to on the remote machine **change the password of the service back to it's old value**.

Note that some services keep a password history and therefore refuse to accept your old password.

This does not completely eliminate the risks that come from a theft password, but it minimizes the time span an attacker would be able to use the password. Depending on the service the password belongs to and how long it takes you to do what you want and change the password back an attacker may already have logged in to the server the password belongs to and may have compromised the account. However this depends on the service, without knowing which service we are talking about it is difficult to guess the potential damage an attack may cause.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the @Robert's points, you may figure out a way to pass a **cookie** of logon session to the remote computer instead. Most web-services even in 2020 accept new IP as long as it has the same cookie. While still a bit tricky, most web-services are accessible via browser, you may prompt the remote machine to install the cookie management extension to the browser (such as "Edit Cookie"), and instead of logging on manually, just set up your logged-on cookie from the host machine. Once the remote session is over, log out of the session, hence making the remote machine's cookie useless just as well